# Parent path Python Maya

Tags: python, user-interface, maya

I have a problem. I have a GUI in maya generated by a script in python.
The GUI, when launched opens an image.To load the image I used the following line of code:

```
cmds.image( image='/home/s4915717/myName/artefacts/Images/UIheader02.png' )
```

As you can understand, if I move my script into another computer, I should manually change the path to correctly load the image. 
Is there a way to prevent this and let the program find to allocation of the image by itself?

I also tried to use the following method:

```
import os
.
.
.
path = os.path.abspath('myName/artefacts/Images/UIheader02.png')
cmds.image( image=path )
```

it works on my pc, but if I move on another one it doesn't work(yes I moved the whole folder with the image inside myName/artefacts...

Answer (score 0):

Your first path is absolute, your second is relative, which may be part of your issue.

Depending on your OS, Maya looks in slightly different places in the user directory for icons.  See [this page in the docs](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-228CCA33-4AFE-4380-8C3D-18D23F7EAC72-htm.html) down near the bottom, under `XBMLANGPATH` for the locations Maya is expecting.  You can also set `XBMLANGPATH` to a custom location before starting Maya if you want to point at a special place, like a network share.

Answer (score 0):

If your script is called from a file outside of Maya, you can use the `__file__` attribute which will give you the path to the file where you use it. You can then use it to build your path.

For example, if your script is stored in '/home/s4915717/myName/artefacts', the `__file__` will return '/home/s4915717/myName/artefacts'
So `__file__ + '/Images/UIheader02.png'` will give you the full path : '/home/s4915717/myName/artefacts/Images/UIheader02.png'

The safest way is probably to have all your scripts stored in a specific folder (for example the Maya script file) from which you can build relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

Like Martin mentioned, you can use `__file__` within your script and it will return that script's full path.

So let's say you have your image in a folder with your script like so:

```
+--my_script.py
+--my_folder
|    +--my_image.png
```

You can access the image in your script this way:

```
import os
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "my_folder", "my_image.png")
```

And let's say your folder was up one directory like so:

```
+--my_image.png
+--my_folder
|    +--my_script.py
```

You can use `os.path.abspath` instead:

```
import os
os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, "..", "..", "my_image.png"))
```

`abspath` helps resolve the `".."` to go up a directory. At the end you can use `os.path.exists` to verify that the resulting path does in fact exist.